# What will be custom scheduler name in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have ran service account and pod for custom scheduler.so what will be my custom scheduler name ?it will be pod name or service name or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you define your scheduler name while writing the scheduler itself. Then you create a docker container for scheduler and ran that scheduler as deployment in kubernetes.

Now that scheduler will schedule your pods (based on how you write your scheduling).

You should watch the following talk of Kelsey Hightower on how to write custom scheduler and use it

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYcL0Un1io0

Here is the toy scheduler source code, you can refer

> https://github.com/kelseyhightower/scheduler

Hope this gives you brief idea.

EDIT:

The kelsey hightower's scheduler (link mentioned above) has to be deployed in following way:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: scheduler
  name: scheduler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scheduler
      name: scheduler
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: scheduler
          image: kelseyhightower/scheduler:0.4.0
        - name: kubectl
          image: kelseyhightower/kubectl:1.3.4
          args:
            - "proxy"
```

Then whenever you deploy new pods with that scheduler you need to provide `schedulerName' in yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
      name: nginx
    spec:
      schedulerName: hightower
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: "nginx:1.11.1-alpine"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: "128M"
```

That `schedulerName` should be the name of the scheduler define in your code.

Comment: I got it but other deployment which will use that scheduler,there in yaml file what will be schedulername field.is it depoyment name of custom scheduler pod or anything else?

Comment: You need to write the function in your scheduler to do so. However now you can have multiple scheduler so that you can schedule using your specific requirements and also have default scheduler to have standard tuning like nodeSelector etc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/

Comment: Yeah,I checked that thing.if I use node_selector for default scheduler, node is assigned when nodeselector matched,but this case custom scheduler nodename is not assigned with nodeselctor matching.will happen once nodename we change by scheduler only.